# How can I use the return of a MAPLE procedure as a function directly

Tags: maple

This may be very basic, but I can't seem to figure it out:  I am trying to use the output of a procedure directly as a function.  The Procedure is a prefabricated one, namely the dsolve option in MAPLE.  Specifically, I would like to say

```
dsolve({diff(y(t), t) = y(t)*t, y(1) = 1}, y(t), series, t = 1, order = 7)
```

The result is

```
y(t) = t+1-1+(t-1)^2+(2/3)*(t-1)^3+(5/12)*(t-1)^4+(13/60)*(t-1)^5+(19/180)*(t-1)^6+O((t-1)^7)
```

Which is great, but I can't use this as a function directly, i.e., when I type in y(3), I get y(3).  I'm sure this is because the procedure is returning a statement instead of a function.  I guess the most basic way around this would be to copy and paste the expression and say y:=t->   whatever, but this is inelegant.  How can I get around this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are getting back an equation of the form `y(t)=<some series>` from your `dsolve` call.

```
dsol := dsolve({diff(y(t), t) = y(t)*t, y(1) = 1}, y(t), series, t = 1, order = 5);

                                      2   2        3   5         4    /       5\
  dsol := y(t) = 1 + (t - 1) + (t - 1)  + - (t - 1)  + -- (t - 1)  + O\(t - 1) /
                                          3            12
```

You can also convert the series structure on the right-hand side of that to a polynomial (ie. get rid of the big-O term).

```
convert( dsol, polynom );

                             2   2        3   5         4
           y(t) = t + (t - 1)  + - (t - 1)  + -- (t - 1) 
                                 3            12
```

You can also evaluate the expression you want, `y(t)`, at that equation. (Or you could just use the `rhs` command. For sets of equations in the multivariable case the `eval` approach is more robust and straighforward.)

```
eval( y(t), convert( dsol, polynom ) );

                          2   2        3   5         4
               t + (t - 1)  + - (t - 1)  + -- (t - 1) 
                              3            12
```

And, finally, you can also produce an operator from this expression.

```
Y := unapply( eval( y(t), convert( dsol, polynom ) ), t );

                               2   2        3   5         4
          Y := t -> t + (t - 1)  + - (t - 1)  + -- (t - 1) 
                                   3            12
```

That operator is a procedure, and can be applied to whatever point you want.

```
 Y(3);
                                 19
```

The way I have it above, the statement which assigns to `Y` happens to contain all the individual steps. And that's the only statement above which you'd need to execute, to get the operator that I assigned to `Y`.If you prefer you could do each step separately and assign each intermediate result to some name. It just depends on whether you want them for any other purpose.

```
restart:
dsol := dsolve({diff(y(t), t) = y(t)*t, y(1) = 1}, y(t), series, t = 1, order = 5):
peq := convert( dsol, polynom ):
p := eval( y(t), peq ):
Y := unapply( p, t ):
Y(3);

                                 19
```

Comment: This is absolutely clear and 100% perfect.  Thank you so much!