# Cannot assign Maple function by directly using expression, only by referencing output

Tags: maple

Why does this does not work for assigning a function:

```
F(t) := Matrix(matrixDE(A, t)[1])
```

While using a label to reference the output works:

```
Matrix(matrixDE(A, t)[1])      (1)
F1(t) := (1)

matrixDE(A, t)[1]              (2)
F2(t) := Matrix((2))
```

It seems the indexing operation `[1]` is what poses the problem, but I don't understand the mechanic behind this.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816700/how-can-i-use-the-return-of-a-maple-procedure-as-a-function-directly) but it did not make me any wiser...

---

**Edit:**

I ended up getting my desired effect using `eval` and :

```
F(x) := eval(Matrix(matrixDE(A, t)[1]), t = x)
```

The price to pay being that the argument of `F`is named `x` instead of `t`.

Comment: Your use of **eval** like this is syntactically correct, but I don't think that it gives you what you truly want. I don't know for sure because I haven't seen your full problem. But I think that you want to call **matrixDE** *once* for symbolic **t** and then substitute numeric values for **t** in the resulting Matrix. Is that correct? But the above use of **eval** will cause the symbolic computation performed by **matrixDE** to be redone *every time* that you use a new value of **x**. That's not what you want, correct?

Comment: You are correct that it's not what I truly want, but it was good enough in this case where my main motivators were curiosity and convenience. But I did not fully think through the implication of a later change of A resulting in a change of F(x), which seems like something that can lead to hard-to-catch errors, so thanks for your comment.

Comment: If **matrixDE** is a procedure that you wrote or whose code you can modify, then you can make a slight change in its return value so that it returns the procedure **F** itself rather than returning whatever it currently returns (apparently it returns something that can be converted to a Matrix). If you can't modify its code, then you can write a wrapper that returns **F**. Either option requires only one line of code that I'd be happy to help you with.

Comment: I'ts a built-in procedure for differential equations on matrix form, so nothing I can (or want to) change.But I'd be happy if you could show me how to wrap it as to return a procedure! I was trying to do something like that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to with the indexing. The problem is exactly what you said in your title: You cannot (properly) assign a Maple function by directly using an (unevalauted) expression; rather, you must reference the output (or evaluation).

More specifically, it depends on the desired order of these two operations: evaluation of a parameterized expression and substitution of values for the parameter. If you want to first evaluate the expression with a symbolic parameter (your **t** in this case), then the command to use is **unapply**:

```
F:= unapply(Matrix(matrixDE(A, t)[1]), t);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped clear up the terminology! I'll edit in my solution.